# Where was my mistake during this integration, if there is one?

Tags: integration, partial-fractions

I plugged it into an online integral calculator and got different values. I apologize in advance for the hand-writing.

[Problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dtrMi.jpg)

Comment: You had three questions on your image there, the first one ?

Comment: Yes, sorry about that!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a mistake in the long division 
In first step  $-x^2$    not  $-2x^2$ 
And all steps is right

Comment: Ugh, appreciate it ._.